# ¿ Cómo mostrar una cookie desde un webAPI con Net 6 en el navegador(localhost)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, webapi, refreshtoken

Saludo, muchas gracias por detenerte a leer mi pregunta, veras tengo el siguiente "problema"
Estoy desarrollando un web api con C# y Net 6, para lo cual estoy implementado el uso de JWT y su respectivo refreshToken, en esete ultimo yo creo una cookie de respuesta httpOnly, por lo que yo establesco la siguiente configuracion al momento de crearla.

```
 private void SetRefreshTokenInCookie(string refreshToken, HostString domain)
    {
        var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
        {
            HttpOnly = true,
            IsEssential = true,
            Secure = false,
            SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
            Domain = "localhost", //using https://localhost:44340/ here doesn't work
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7)
        };
        Response.Cookies.Append("refreshToken", refreshToken, cookieOptions);
    }
```

En postman, como es de costumbre todo funciona perfectamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo mismo pasa cuando invoco el metodo de mi refresh token que es el que me interesa, mi cookie si llega a mi controlador desde postman:

1.- peticion postman con headers:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2.- Controlador web api

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui claramente se recibe el refresh token de la cookie que se coloca en postaman.

Ahora en donde tengo este problema es en mi aplicacíon de frontend, creada con VUEJS y usando axios, la peticion de inicio de sesion es satisfactoria, si hay una conexion entre mi front y back
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

SIN EMBARGO! aqui es donde entra mi problema, ya que en mi apartado de cookies no obtengo nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al no tener esta cookie, al ejecutar el metodo de mi controlador no recibe nada, solo recibe un null, a diferencia de cuando lo ejecuto con postman.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como seria la implemntacion correcta o que es lo que me faltaria por configurar:

Mi fronted corre en: http://127.0.0.1:5173
Y mi backend corre en: https://localhost:7072

Realmente es la primera vez que estoy trabajando con fronted y backend separado asi que realmente aprecio toda la yuda posible, y consejos.

Comment: Y si corres el frontend en http://localhost:5173, pasa lo mismo?

Comment: Justo acabo de probrar tu sugerencia, y si en efecto. mi cookie no se coloca en el navegador ya lo intente en mozilla, chrome y en edge pero en todos me da los mismo

Answer (score 1):

Despues de todo un dia, por fin pude dar con la solución.

1. No estaba realizando una peticion de forma correcta, ya que no incluia el atributo withCredentials en mis peticiones.

Por lo que el primer paso fue añadirlo.

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
```

hecho esto, ahora mi webAPI me mostraba un errors de cors, y eso es debido a que ahora los CORS deben de aceptar las credenciales, por lo que mi politica quedo de la siguiente manera:

```
options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
   builder
   .WithOrigins("http://127.0.0.1:5173","*")
    //.AllowAnyOrigin() //
   .AllowAnyMethod() // With Methods("Get,Post")
   .AllowAnyHeader()
   .AllowCredentials()
 );
```

Ahora, como ultimo paso fue modificar las opciones de mi refreshToken, ya que
al usar: SameSite = SameSiteMode.None es necesario estabceler la opcion secure en true, (Como se puede observar en mi pregunta en ningun momento la indico y en consola mostraba un waning en los datos de mi peticion (No en lo que devuleve axios) )

Esa advertencia al final del renglon me indicaba un warning que mostraba lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No pude capturar lo que se muestra al pasar el mouse sobre el warning, sin embargo no se puede establecer una cookie, si esta no contiene la propiedad secure, cuando se indicaca que una cookie es del tipo

```
 SameSite = SameSiteMode.None
```

Por lo que ahora como ultimo paso, se modifica la configuracion del cookie:

```
var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
        {
            SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
            Domain = null,
            IsEssential = true,
            HttpOnly = true,
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
            Path = "/",
            Secure = true
        };
        Response.Cookies.Append("refreshToken", refreshToken, cookieOptions);
```

siendo esto, ya la respuesta y paso final.

Si bien la cookie no se establece en la pestaña de aplicacion, yo ahora si la tengo alamcenada ya en el navegador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y al ejecutar el metodo de refreshToken ahora si, ya se puede recibir la cookie:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y devolviendome la cookie sin problemas y alamacenando para realizar la siguiente peticion de refresh token.

Siento si la respuesta es muy extensa, y que pueda ayudar a alguien :D